# How do I add key-value to variable without overriding existing data?

Tags: go

I am trying to create a simple cache just using a variable and I don't know how to add to it without completely overriding it each time.

Here is a snippet:

```
package main

var store map[string][]byte

type Routes struct{}

func NewRoutes() *Routes {
    return &Routes{}
}

func (c *Routes) SetRoutes(key string, routes []byte) error {
    store[key] = routes

    return nil
}

func main() {
    routes := NewRoutes()

    routes.SetRoutes("key", []byte("routes"))
}
```

This will result in `panic: assignment to entry in nil map`. I can use `make()` to create the store slice - but I don't want to do that as I believe I would lose whatever was already in the slice rendering it useless.

How can I do this in go?

https://go.dev/play/p/NbqSbSTx5ER

Comment: Why would initializing a map cause you to lose the data in the slice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a global variable store, while most likely you want to encapsulate it in your Routes struct:

```golang
package main

type Routes struct{
    store map[string][]byte
}

func NewRoutes() *Routes {
    return &Routes{
        store: make(map[string][]byte),
    }
}

func (c *Routes) SetRoutes(key string, routes []byte) error {
    c.store[key] = routes

    return nil
}

func main() {
    routes := NewRoutes()

    routes.SetRoutes("key", []byte("routes"))
}
```

See: https://go.dev/play/p/3M4kAfya6KE. This ensures the map is scoped to your Routes struct and only initialised once.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if it is `nil` and `make` if it is:

```
func (c *Routes) SetRoutes(key string, routes []byte) error {
    if store == nil {
        store = make(map[string][]byte)
    }
    store[key] = routes
    return nil
}
```

Alternatively, just make it in the `main` func:

```
func main() {
    store = make(map[string][]byte)
    routes := NewRoutes()
    routes.SetRoutes("key", []byte("routes"))
}
```